# Document class birkjour

Tags: texmaker

I prepared a short document in Texmaker following the Birkhäuser protocols for `\documentclass{birkjour}`. After saving and reloading the QuickBuild gives

> "Could not start command"

and preview PDF gives

> "File not found".

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: Welcome in this wonderful community. QuickBuild is it an editor of LaTeX?

Comment: do you get the same error with article class (usual reason for getting that command is unrelated to teh document, simply that tex is not found, have you installed tex as well as texmaker?)

Comment: The distribution `birkjour.zip` contains `bjourdoc.tex`. Were you able to compile it succefully ? http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/814998/application/zip/birkjour.zip

Comment: Thanks. I installed MikTex and was able to compile with \documentclass{article}. The problem may be that the document was prepared with Scientific Workplace (no longer in business) whose macros do not seem to recognize birkjour.